# Racing condition with DOM manipulation, ng-repeat and ng-class animation in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate, ng-class

I have an issue with my project but I can't tell where it comes from.

I am coding a game where the users have to pick the right city given 3 different cities and a map with a pointer on an anonymous location. Then I change the classes of the 3 buttons with ng-class (and an animation) to show the right answer in green and the wrong answers in red.

Then, after a certain delay, the model changes to show the next 3 cities to choose from.

3/4 of the time, my code behaves correctly, but 1/4 of the time, there is a second where the browser displays too many elements, like if the model contained 6 cities and not 3 (it shows actually the last 3 and the new ones).

I did a JSFiddle to explain my point, but it works everytime unlike my project, maybe because the digest cycles are less packed with events.

http://jsfiddle.net/HnWt2/4/

I added a $timeout when the model (labels) changes.

```
$scope.$watch('count', function (c) {
        var t = 0;
        c === 0 ? t = 0 : t = 1000;

        $timeout(function () {
            timeout = false;

            //THIS ONE
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.labels = data[c];
            });
        }, t);
});
```

It doesn't change anything in JSFiddle but seems to help a lot in my project. Without the timeout, the issue was happening everytime.

Here's a **[screen recording](http://youtu.be/9_9xqIbCxmg)** of my issue, maybe someone could explain to me what's wrong here.

---

*In case somebody wants to see the whole code*

**My controller**

```
//GAME CONTROLLER
tp2Controllers.controller('GameController', function($log, $scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, $timeout) {

  //Si les donnees de jeu n'ont pas reussi a etre telechargees
  if ($rootScope.gamedata == undefined) {
    $scope.showError = true;
  }

  //Initialisation des variables
  $scope.timerRunning = true;
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.score = 0;
  $scope.showbar = true;
  $scope.showLobbyButton = false;
  $scope.endGameMessage = '';
  $scope.valid = 0;
  var timeout = false;

  //On surveille le nombre de tours
  $scope.$watch('count', function(c) {
    $scope.valid = getValidIndex();
    var t = 0;
    c == 0 ? t = 0 : t = 800;
    $timeout(function() {
      timeout = false;
      if (c == 15) $scope.finished();
      if ($rootScope.gamedata != undefined) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.choices = $rootScope.gamedata[c];
        });
      }
    }, t);
  });

  function getValidIndex() {
    if ($scope.choices != undefined) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ($scope.choices[i].flag == 1) return i;
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.getClass = function(index) {
    if (timeout) {
      if (index == $scope.valid) {
        return "btn-success";
      } else {
        return "btn-danger";
      }
    } else {
      return "btn-info";
    }
  };

  //Fonction lors du clique sur le bouton associe a une ville
  $scope.pickChoice = function(index) {
    if (timeout === false) {
      timeout = true;
      if (index == $scope.valid) {
        $scope.score++;
      }
      $scope.count++;
    }
  };

  //Fin de partie
  $scope.finished = function() {
    $scope.showbar = false;
    $scope.endGameMessage = "Votre score est de " + $scope.score + "!";
    var sendData = {
      score: $scope.score,
      username: $rootScope.username
    };
    //Requete AJAX pour enregistrer les scores
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'backend/endgame.php',
      data: sendData
    }).success(function(data) {
      $scope.showLobbyButton = true;
    }).error(function(data) {
      $scope.endGameMessage = "Le score n'a pas pu etre enregistre. Une erreur technique est survenue.";
    });
  };
});
```

**My view**

```
<div class="container game-container">
    <div ng-show="showbar">
        <timer interval="1000" countdown="60" finish-callback="finished()" ng-hide="showError">
            <div class="progress progress-striped active countdown-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" style="width: {{ (seconds == 0) && '0' || (100 - ( seconds / 60 * 100 ))}}%;"></div>
            </div>
        </timer>
        <br>
        <div class="choices">
            <a class="btn gamebtn" ng-class="getClass($index)" ng-repeat="choice in choices"
            ng-click="pickChoice($index)" ng-cloak>{{choice.nom}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="score">
            <!-- {{score}} -->
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="showError">Game data is not loaded! Go back to <a href="#/lobby">lobby!</a> 
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="animate-show" ng-show="endGameMessage">
        <div class="alert alert-success">{{endGameMessage}}</div>
        <a href="#/lobby" class="btn btn-primary">Retournez au lobby</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.4s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.4s;
}
```

ps. Sorry for the french commentaries, there are not that important anyway. And yeah, my controller is a fat ****.

Comment: Sorry, but your logic is awful since you're using timeout inside timeout.

Comment: Yeah I guess so! :D Switching for quick-ng-repeat I could remove the inner timeout!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be with ng-repeat (or my asynchronous coding skills). Switching for [quick-ng-repeat](https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat) fixed the issue!